# How to use dependencies in a Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, dependencies, swift-package

I created a new **Package** with Xcode and incorporated a dependency, however when I try to use it, I get an error.

[image: Swift Package Error]

How do I use the dependency in the Package sources? In a normal project, I can easily import and use AgileDB.

Here's the Package:

```
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "DBCore",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "DBCore",
            targets: ["DBCore"]),
    ],

    dependencies: [
          .package(url: "https://github.com/AaronBratcher/AgileDB", from: "6.4.0")
    ],

    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.

        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.

        .target(
            name: "DBCore",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "DBCoreTests",
            dependencies: ["DBCore"]),
    ]
)
```

Perhaps the AgileDB package as a dependency in the target? I tried copying that and it won't recognize it.

Comment: Inside `AgileDB` check file `Package`. That will have something like `name: "X"`. Try using that in your import

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi The name is `AgileDB` and can be found here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/AgileDB

Comment: I have added a detailed answer explaining how to add a Library. Please check if you have maybe missed a step here or all the required entries are present as outlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer.

In the target dependencies, need to include the package name as a string:

```
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.

        .target(
            name: "DBCore",
            dependencies: [
                    "AgileDB"
                ]),

        .testTarget(
            name: "DBCoreTests",
            dependencies: ["DBCore"]),
    ]
```

Answer (score -3):

Step by step guide:

[image]

1. Open project settings
2. Click on "Package Dependencies"
3. Click on the "Plus" icon and add your package in the window that opens
4. Your added package should appear in the list

[image]

5. Package should also appear under "Package Dependencies" in the left bar

[image]

6. Click on your target
7. Navigate to "General" tab and "Frameworks and Libraries" section under that
8. Click on "Plus" icon and select/add your package in the window that opens
9. Your added package should appear in the list

[image]

10. Package should automatically be added in "Build Phases" tab under "Link Binary with Libraries" section. If it isn’t add it by clicking the "Plus" icon

At this point you should be able to import and use the package in any of the files under this target.

Comment: My "Project" is a Swift Package. See the picture in my question. There is no project or targets as you specify in your directions. What you show is good, however I already have that working elsewhere.

I recommend deleting this answer.